# vue-router doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: vue.js, button, vuejs2, vue-router

i added vuetify button to change URL but it is only work with computer not with mobile device and when i use mobile size devtool in google chrome it not works again..
and its my Button

```
<v-card
 class="mx-3 my-12 d-flex"
 max-width="800"
 max-heigh="230"
 v-for="(item, index) in films"
 :key="index"
>
 <v-card-text class="d-flex py-2">
  <v-chip-group
     v-for="(zhaner, index) in item.zhaner"
     :key="index"
     class="d-flex">
   <v-chip>{{ zhaner }}</v-chip>
  </v-chip-group>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <v-btn rounded default :to="'/film/' + item.name">
   See More...
  </v-btn>
 </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

i added another button to change theme and it was worked just this one doesn't work and when i go to the link by writing url custom its not work and not show me anything (On Mobile)..
and its my router file

```
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/film/:name",
    name: "FilmPage",
    component: FilmPage,
  }
```

And its script tag to get the props and template tag..

```
<template>
 <div>
  {{ getPage }}
  <v-container>
    <Header :filmInfo="film" />
    <div class="d-flex justify-space-between flex-wrap">
     <Movies :filmInfo="film" />
     <Infos :filmInfo="film" />
    </div>
  <v-container>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "../components/Film/header";
import Movies from "../components/Film/movie";
import Infos from "../components/Film/infos";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      film: null,
      data: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getPage() {
      this.data = this.$route.params.name;
      this.film = this.$store.state.films.find((i) => i.name === this.data);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    document.title = "Film";
  },
  components: {
    Header,
    Movies,
    Infos,
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's hard to know the reason (router related to project scope, not to copy-paste of one vue component). Maybe clear Cache (+ inspect chrome and check for errors + inspect the output HTML). **maybe you use a diff button on mobile VS desktop (hide/show). **maybe you forgot to publish the changes  (you work on localhost but on mobile, you test the "live 
 not updated website").

Comment: i created project before and never faces this problem (Routing), and its not work even in google chrome devtool on mobile size and i don't know why

Comment: Try to add more complete example (include your router settings and so on). Maybe her: https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Ok Bro, i Added

Comment: Although it might not be the best possible solution, have you tried using a custom click handler using `@click.native`? Also, try running your project in a browser with Vue DevTools enabled and check out the router there.